# Upgrade to Facebook Graph API v2.7 or higher

Tags: spring, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I have a Java website that uses Spring Social for integration with Facebook (account registration and sign-in with a Facebook email address). Here is what I have in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Recently, I got an email from Facebook regarding API upgrade:

> Your App is currently accessing Graph API v2.6 which will reach the
>   end of its 2-year lifetime on 13 July, 2018. We estimate 2 endpoints
>   that your app calls will be impacted by this change and may stop
>   working after the automatic upgrade push. To ensure a smooth
>   transition, please migrate all calls to Graph API v2.7 or higher. Use
>   the API Upgrade Tool to understand exactly how this change will impact
>   your app

Note that I only use the integration for account registration and user sign-in on my site. For account registration, I only need a person's email address from Facebook.

I am not sure how to handle this. I am not able to find any release newer than

```
2.0.3.RELEASE
```

Any info or advice is really appreciated.